# Improve Garbage Collection for Lots of Young Generation Invocations

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

We have an application with OpenJDK 1.8 (mostly spent in TCP/network calls, inbound/outbound) which exhibits ***plenty*** of GC young generation invocations, raising the overall heap consumption just below the max amount in a short span of time, and then triggers a Full GC, where the heap size is reduced to pre-young generation rapid calls.

What garbage collection should be utilized to have a more elongated seesaw graph as opposed to a very choppy young generation ups and downs?

Is there a way to also instruct GC to trigger Full GC when it gets 15% below the max heap, rather than almost touching the max heap then executing a full GC?

Comment: What GC options do you have enabled, if any?

Comment: A default one which Java 8 uses, Parallel GC.

Comment: Can you provide GC logging may be?

Comment: You need to post more information than you have here. GC logs would be very useful as well as the output from including -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal on the command line. Without this, it's not realistic to expect an answer to this kind of question.

Comment: "young generation invocations" is not a thing. Apparently, you mean *allocations*, in which case, it's a tautology. It's the standard for allocations to happen in the young generation. But it's not clear why a filled young generation should cause a Full GC. Further, sharp edges in the graph imply that the GC ran fast and managed to reclaim a lot of memory quickly. You are basically asking "how can I make the GC inefficient"...

Comment: To add to @Holger's comment: the gc behaviour seems consistent with the creation of a lot of short lived objects, which is generally regarded as good.

Comment: @Holger I thought the context is clear here. I was referring to GC invocations against the young/survivor regions, and not the memory allocations in those regions. And many times, these surviving objects will be moved to tenure region, which will trigger a Full GC invocation. If the rise in GC young generation is rapid, when it gets close to the max heap size, and if there is a large memory allocation request, e.g. request spike, it might not be able to service such request and throw OOME.

Comment: @Erik If they are being moved to Tenure region, and we get close to the max heap size, and if there is a huge spike all of a sudden, then there is an OOME risk since Full GC hasn't been invoked to clean up the heap. I was wondering if there is a way to trigger Full GC, say, when the heap usage gets to 10% below the max heap size. That way, if there is a spike, the application would be safe since Full GC has been invoked before getting very close to max heap size.

Comment: What you are describing now, implies that the objects are *still in use*, as otherwise, they wouldn’t get moved to the old generation, further, when the subsequent Full GC still can’t remove them, it implies that even by that time, they are still in use. An option to trigger the Full GC earlier wouldn’t help then. You simply need more memory. Or change the application, to reduce its memory consumption.

Comment: What @Holger said. You might have a memory leak or consume more memory than you have budget for.

Comment: @Holger, But the Full GC invocation does clean up the tenure region as described in the original question. The problem as I stated is that the Full GC invocation occurs when the memory usage gets very close to the max heap size, and therefore, if there is a spike in memory allocation request by the application, then we run into trouble. Setting heap size higher exhibits the same behavior (but with lesser probability of this issue occurring). My question is, is there a way to trigger Full GC automatically when it gets 10% below max heap size rather than waiting till the last moment?

Comment: That’s still a contradiction. When “a spike in memory allocation request” is capable of triggering an `OutOfMemoryError`, then you don’t have enough memory. When the garbage collector can’t reclaim the memory when the spike happens, performing the garbage collection earlier doesn’t change that. The lifetime of an object is simple, “in use”→“not in use”. It doesn’t matter where in the first phase a garbage collection happens.

Comment: @Holger I see what you are saying. In other word, lets say the memory usage (heap) is at 99% before Full GC invocation, and the application makes an additional 10% memory above that 99%. You are saying, the spike should invoke a Full GC, reclaim enough memory to service that 10% allocation. If it doesn't, then something else is going (objects are still being referenced from the root path and cannot be cleaned up). Am I correct in my assumption? That said, again, if we can configure GC to trigger a Full GC at 90% max heap, won't that give the app some time to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The problem is, even if I give the application more memory, it always moves objects to tenure region to the point that it gets close to max size, then, and only then, it invokes a Full GC, at which point, everything goes back to normal. Besides, these climbs are steep enough that Full GC invocations do happen in short intervals which I presume is not a good thing, but that's another discussion.

Comment: I don’t know which GC you are using but A) non-concurrent collectors stop the application and eliminate everything possible, without the possibility that the application can perform additional allocations in the meanwhile, whereas B) concurrent collector trigger the full gc much earlier than 90% already. But when the application eats up the remaining memory during the concurrent collection, it turns to a non-concurrent collection anyway. If this still fails, then yes, the objects must be still reachable. Triggering the gc earlier gives the application *less time* to finish using the objects.